# How do deniers of the personhood of the Holy Spirit interpret Romans 8:26-27?

Tags: exegesis, pneumatology, romans, intercession, emotions

Romans 8:26-27 (ESV):

> 26 Likewise the Spirit helps us in our weakness. For we do not know what to pray for as we ought, **but the Spirit himself intercedes for us with groanings too deep for words**. 27 And he who searches hearts knows what is **the mind of the Spirit**, because **the Spirit intercedes for the saints** according to the will of God.

This is one of the most commonly cited passages as evidence ***for*** the personhood of the Holy Spirit (e.g. as in [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/44245/50422)), probably because of the following reasons:

- The Holy Spirit is said to be able to intercede (i.e. pray) for the saints.
- And not just intercede, but intercede with groanings too deep for words (indicative of emotions?)
- Moreover, the Holy Spirit is explicitly said to have a mind (*the mind of the Spirit*, v27).

In short, the passage appears to be saying that the Holy Spirit has (1) a mind, (2) emotions and (3) the ability to pray/intercede.

**Question**: How do deniers of the personhood of the Holy Spirit interpret Romans 8:26-27 and make sense of all this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124524/discussion-on-question-by-spirit-realm-investigator-how-do-deniers-of-the-person).

Comment: This might be a better case against the personhood of holy ghost than most of the below (not my case and not my opinion. For now, I dont know, just sharing): https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/63501/43095
Ending with:
**In the  Greek language and the Greek Koine the “holy spirit” is NEVER spoken of with a personal pronoun. It is a “which”, not a “who”. It is always an “it, not a “he” or” who” or whom.**

Comment: I looked at John 16:13, eg in the link: “Some trinitarian scholars reject this.. the masculine pronoun, they argue, can legitimately refer to the masculine noun Helper, not Spirit, even though (esp in John 16:13,14) they aren’t in close proximity.” \ While it’s true about the proximity, we have essentially: “The Helper ..., new verse He, new verse He, new verse He, etc, with an entirely unbroken chain. So briefly saying “Spirit of Truth”, in yet another He verse keeps that, proximity aside. “He” would be used for Helper if that was an It, due to gender, but not for Spirit if that was an It

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plain bible teaching does not entertain strange ideas of a holy spirit person.

There is no need for us to use creative imagination to arrive at the fanciful ideas as those construed by men writing 100’s of years after Christ and his apostles taught a simple truth about the one God the Father and His human son, Jesus.

No bible verse teaches the ‘person’ of Holy Spirit. But many are developed with erroneous logic and interpretation to make up such a thing.

The OP has noted several items supposedly indicating this person’s activities. This is a good example of reading into the text that which is simply not there. While it may form part of traditional dogma, that is irrelevant.

Let’s rather read the chapter in context and note how this spirit is mentioned.

- For in Christ Jesus the law of the Spirit of life
- controlled not by the flesh, but by the Spirit
- if anyone does not have the Spirit of Christ
- if you live according to the flesh, you will die; but if by the Spirit
- Spirit of sonship
- firstfruits of the Spirit
- the Spirit helps us in our weakness
- the mind of the Spirit

None of this requires us to think in ‘person’ terms. No Apostle did either or taught such a thing in the entire NT.

What is meant by ‘the mind of the spirit’? Simply that mind in each person, like Christ’s, which was in accord with God. It is not describing the *mind* of a spirit *person*, but of the *kind* of mind each human has that God is specifically involved with. The mind set on life, on peace, on truth- just as Jesus’ was.

> Let this mind be in you which was also in Christ. Jesus Phil 2:5

Of course, our minds are still influenced by both good and evil, but when God’s spirit is involved, maturity and overcoming is the objective and fruit.

“He who searches the hearts” *knows*, *recognises*, this mind of God active in each believer or *saint* as v27 puts it -

> according to the will of God.

Jesus had the mind of God working in him by the Holy Spirit in him. That he had his own independent and differing will, shows clearly that he also had to learn and *choose* the right way just as we all do - heeding that spirit of truth, wisdom and love that guides us toward the light.

What is the Holy Spirit? No more or less than the presence of God interacting within creation and His creatures. Joining with our carnal minds to change their course and purpose from a selfish, prideful pursuit, to a more Kingdom-centred focus.

The spirit of sonship, of truth, of Christ is all the same effect of having God close to us - not nearly quite as close as Jesus experienced, but the exact same influence anyway.

The spirit intercedes- When we respond to the guidance of God in us, His spirit adds to what we can accomplish. Granting another aspect to our person that we do not naturally have - the fruits of His spirit in us - Gal 5

There are many examples of the bible showing us what the Holy Spirit is and helpful in eliminating what it is not.

The [disciples](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/53177/is-holy-spirit-the-spirit-of-the-father-according-to-luke-and-matthew/55619?r=SearchResults#55619) understood.

Most translators don’t as they insist on ‘he’ and ‘him’ everywhere, which is unwarranted and unnecessary from the Greek. This has caused much confusion and perpetuated the extra-biblical writings which have sought to supplant God’s word with an illogical and unholy construct.

We might continue to ask similar questions of every verse mentioning the Holy Spirit and diligently read in the same old extra bits that help uphold the traditional teaching. This is a fruitless endeavour as it requires ignoring the broad narrative of the NT and the complete silence of clear and definite passages that *do* reveal a Holy Spirit person.

When a dogma requires a ‘reading bits in’ approach, it should be discouraged.

More on the, ‘[Not a Holy Spirit person](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/82813/what-is-the-biblical-basis-against-the-personhood-of-the-holy-spirit/82814#82814)’.

Comment: A deeper look at the word translated "mind" might be in order.  It is a word that describes the process of translating the emotions developed through what the senses perceive into a verbal, rational, logical expression of those emotions.  This is the "mind" of the Spirit.  It is not God acknowledging and responding to whatever level of Himself He perceives in a person.  The Spirit, in this passage, is perceiving and translating to God what is seen in a person.  More like a person than a thing.

Comment: "creative imagination" is required to dodge the Biblical sayings, which clearly identify the Holy Ghost as an actual personage capable of providing companionship, comfort, teaching, revelation, remembrance, intercession, prayer, and many other attributes unique to personhood. That imagination was the effect of the creeds, not of the word of God.

Answer (score -1):

The latest comments exchanged between myself, Miguel de Servet, and Nigel J, should  already provide something more that a hint to an answer.

Anyway, the Spirit (*pneuma*/*ruach*), of which we read, in particular, at Romans 8:26-27, is **neither** a "person", **nor** a "personification": like the Word (*logos*/*dabar*) it (it ..) is an **eternal, essential attribute** of the One and only God, the Father Almighty.

Comment: What does it mean for an "attribute" of God to intercede with God on our behalf?

Comment: @curious It means that God, since the Pentecost, has "planted" His Spirit in His faithful, as a source of inspiration, so that the Church **responds** to God's stimulation, ideally, mirroring God's mind and intentions.

Comment: Attribute as in; God is Love, God is Spirit, God is Immutable, etc?

Comment: No, more like powers, _dynameis_: God's Word/_logos_/_dabar_ and His Spirit/_pneuma_/_ruach_ are His two essential powers. Is this compatible with God's "simplicity"? I don't know, and I don't care. Anyway, advocates of a tri-une, tri-personal Godhead will have to convince me that the "trinity" is compatible with God's "simplicity".

Comment: @MigueldeServet devils are spirits. Unclean spirits are spirits. How are the agents of God to perform anything at all on His behalf if the Holy Spirit is not actually a spirit?

Comment: @pygosceles - Do you believe in God's simplicity? Is God's simplicity compatible with a triune, tripersonal God?

Comment: @MigueldeServet I do not think of a mundane notion of simplicity as defining the character of God. I think we need godly terms to describe God. There are more than a few simple statements about God that are unequivocally true, for example, God cannot lie, God cannot sin, and God is good. Is the definition of good or the nature of God easily explained? Perhaps this is not the domain of verbal articulation. If you were to see God, this would answer far more questions than any amount of explanation. The mystery of godliness is great, but that does not mean God is paradoxical. He is One Being.

Comment: @pygosceles _He is One Being_ Even resorting to the philosophical notion of “being” should be inappropriate, according to your criteria.

Comment: @MigueldeServet "Being" is clear enough and is objective. Simplicity is rather more subjective, especially when people let creeds obfuscate the notion. God is understandable. Nonsensicality is not a Divine attribute.

Comment: @pygosceles - Let me disclose to you that the Greek equivalent of “being”, _ousia_ is only found in Luke 15:12,13 in the sense of what one has, i. e. property, possessions, estate.