# According to Trinitarians, can the personhood of the Holy Spirit be confirmed through personal experience?

Tags: nature-of-god, trinity, pneumatology, spirituality, special-revelation

First of all, I'm well aware of the existence of scriptural arguments both *for* ([link](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/44244/50422)) and *against* ([link](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/82813/50422), [link](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/83304/50422)) the personhood of the Holy Spirit. Whether one finds the arguments either *for* or *against* convincing may depend on multiple factors, and I suspect that, just like in the debate of cessationism vs continuationism, *personal experience* must probably play an important role for some individuals.

**Question**: According to (at least some) Trinitarians, can the Holy Spirit's personhood be accepted on the basis of first-hand *personal experience* with the Holy Spirit Himself, directly, instead of simply be accepted and believed on the basis of exegetical arguments? In other words, is it possible for the Holy Spirit to *reveal* His personhood so clearly and evidently to a believer that he or she would no longer have doubts in this regard, as any possible intellectual objections (such as the ones linked in the first paragraph) would be eclipsed by the weight of this undeniable first-hand experiential knowledge?

---

Related: [Are there published testimonies from Christians who had the truth of the Trinity revealed to them through the Holy Spirit?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/86227/50422)

Comment: Are you asking about the credibility of Revelation in general?

Comment: Protestantism doesn't privilege experiential knowledge over revealed scriptural knowledge. This whole enterprise feels very misguided to a Protestant like me.

Comment: John 16:13 _He shall not speak of himself_ The Spirit is come to lead into all truth and to glorify Christ. He, himself, is experienced but that experience is not the focus of the ministration. Those who have prolonged and mature experience of these matters will know His Presence.

Comment: @NigelJ - sure, but just feeling a presence does not automatically guarantee you that said presence has personhood. I can feel the presence of the sun, the wind, hot water, etc. Does that mean that the sun, the wind, etc. have personhood? In contrast, I can verify the personhood of my next-door neighbor, to a reasonable extent at least, because I can hold a two-way conversation with them and interact with them.

Comment: @Geremia - by 'Revelation' do you mean the Book of Revelation? If so, what does that have to do with my question at all? If instead you mean revelation (lowercase), then non-Trinitarians could say that the Bible reveals that the Holy Spirit is just some kind of impersonal spiritual energy or force from God, not a separate being with personhood of its own. See https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/82813/50422.

Comment: @curiousdannii - `Protestantism doesn't privilege experiential knowledge over revealed scriptural knowledge. This whole enterprise feels very misguided to a Protestant like me.` What about experiential knowledge that validates a particular interpretation of revealed scriptural knowledge? Isn't the Christian life much more than just having a philosophical position or an intellectual exercise?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator Well, that's the point. Either you have experienced these things (as a mature Christian) or you have not.

Comment: @NigelJ - I see. So your answer to the question is 'Yes, the personhood of the Holy Spirit can be experientially verified (by a mature Christian)'.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator I've never heard any Protestants even think of things in this way. I doubt any would give an answer to your questions like this, because it's just not what Protestantism is about.

Comment: @curiousdannii - then you should read Nigel's comments above :-)

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator Yes, I am aware of the presence of the Spirit. And (lamentably) aware of His absences also. But I am 70 years old and experienced in these matters.

Comment: Many Trinitarians would witness to their experience of the Spirit in their lives. I'm not sure that experience could distinguish the distinct personhood of the Spirit as compared to, for example, a modalist view of God. We need special revelation to know God in that way.

Comment: @curiousdannii - do Trinitarians believe in modern special revelations?

Comment: @Spirit Some do, some don't.

Comment: I'm not sure what this question is asking. There are tens of thousands of individual trinitarian denominations, and hundreds of millions of trinitarian believers. It is virtually a statistical guarantee that someone somewhere holds this view, and it seems likely some denomination does. This view also seems like the sort of thing not excluded by the deposit of faith held by apostolic churches (ie it can probably be believed as a matter of theological opinion). Are you asking which denominations hold this view explicitly?

Comment: @jaredad7 - I'm not, but you are probably right, answers should indicate the denominational vantage point they defend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intellectual assent and personal experience with regard to the 'personhood' of the Holy Spirit are strange ways to attempt to get Trinitarians responding. Perhaps that's why you have received lots of brief comments but (until now, two full months later) no actual answer. As a believer in the triune nature of the one God, I see your question as showing a failure to understand what the trinity doctrine is all about.

It is a naive to suppose that one way of believing in the personhood of the Holy Spirit can be used instead of another way, and that that will be sufficient. Both ways are combined. God does not reveal anything about his person (which is triune) according to our preference: "Oh God, I'm not an intellectual, and trying to collate all those scriptures just gives me a headache. I would rather have an experience of the person of the Holy Spirit. That will do me!"

Or, if we say to God, "I'm highly suspicious of all those experiences emotional people keep relating. I want to know intellectually that the Holy Spirit is a person. Please keep this grounded in facts that I can assent to" - would that not also be arrogance on our part?

Who are we to tell God that we want one way of verification instead of another?

The Bible is clear that **if we do not believe what God has told us, we will get no further in any pursuit of God**. Belief is a matter of faith in God's trustworthiness - that it is impossible for God to lie - that all his promises are true. God has told us plenty about the Holy Spirit. Those who obediently believe what God has told them experience the power of the Holy Spirit in their lives.

Yet such is God's grace, that he has also bestowed the agency of the Holy Spirit to change the lives and beliefs of those who know hardly anything about God and Christ. Thereafter, they come to learn about this triune God. It is God's prerogative for us to learn, and to have verified to us, whatsoever he pleases.

In order to be converted to saving faith in Christ, the Holy Spirit guided me to search the scriptures first. I totally disbelieved the trinity doctrine, or even that the Holy Spirit was a person, but I had cried out to God for help. In answer, he caused events to unfold in such a way that I was led to a gradual understanding which caused a reversal of my stance. Thus my conversion to Christ was actually based upon coming to 'see' and believe in the orthodoxly Christian doctrine of the trinity. That included learning about and believing in the Holy Spirit in light of what had been revealed to me about the person of Christ. Once I bent my knees in Jesus' name, the rest followed - a mixture of further intellectual understanding combined with experiencing the Holy Spirit at work in my life.

Really and truly, those who think they should be the arbiters of what is intellectually correct (with regard to God) and/or who  think they ought to have personal experiences of the Holy Spirit's personhood are on a hiding to nowhere (spiritually speaking). They will be left none the wiser. **Humility in approaching God** - admitting we can't see further than the end of our [spiritual] nose - **and diligently searching the scriptures to be taught by the Holy Spirit has to be the starting point. Thereafter, God may be pleased to so lead each individual as they need to be led, for God deals with us all as individuals.** But if you start out with your measure of what will be either intellectual or experiential standards God has to meet before you will be convinced, that would be to insult God, Christ, and the blessed Holy Spirit.

Let this scripture be the final word on the matter:

> "If any of you lacks wisdom, he should ask God, who gives generously
> to all without finding fault, and it will be given to him. But when he
> asks, he must believe and not doubt, because he who doubts is like a
> wave of the sea, blown and tossed by the wind. That man should not
> think he will receive anything from the Lord; he is a double-minded
> man, unstable in all he does" (James 1:5-8).

Answer (score -1):

This may be a question that is far more important than most people realize. If the Holy Spirit is a person, should not Christians have more of an awareness of relating to him? Jesus promised to send him as his replacement on earth.

> John 16 7 “But I tell you the truth, it is to your advantage that I go
> away; for if I do not go away, the Helper will not come to you; but if
> I go, I will send Him to you. NASB

If he were anything less than a person, then would he be an adequate and comforting replacement for Jesus? But as you say, your question is more directed to the presence of the Holy Spirit being confirmed through personal experience, and I will cite the biography of one person who reported his own experiences and that of another well-known person and what they said about their relationship with the Holy Spirit. Some people may consider these individuals to be controversial and everyone will have to decide what they choose to believe. After many years of studying a variety of subjects, I try to not be gullible, but I am also careful to not readily dismiss things that I do not have the means to evaluate, especially when it comes to God and the supernatural. It is an important role of the Spirit to guide us into truth. We should also agree that it is very important to not grieve the Holy Spirit. (Eph. 4:30)

A young immigrant  from Israel became a Christian much to the consternation and dismay of his parents. This is some of the testimony taken from his book cited below.

> It was three days before Christmas 1973. The sun was still rising on
> that cold, misty Toronto morning. Suddenly He was there. The Holy
> Spirit entered my room. He was as real to me that morning as the book
> you are holding in your hand is to you. For the next eight hours I had
> an incredible experience with the Holy Spirit. It changed the course
> of my life. Tears of wonder and joy coursed down my cheeks as I opened
> the Scriptures and He gave me the answers to my questions…. [I]t was
> pure joy. Yes, it was unspeakable. Yes, it was full of glory! If you
> had told me just forty-eight hours earlier what was about to happen to
> me, I would have said, "No way." But from that very moment the Holy
> Spirit became alive in my life. He was no longer a distant "third
> person" of the Trinity. He was real. He had a personality.  pp. 11-12

A friend had invited this 21 year old seeker to attend a service where the healing evangelist, Katherine Kuhlman would be ministering. During worship, even though it was winter and the windows were closed, he felt a draft like waves of wind that washed over him. He wanted to talk to the Lord but all he could do was whisper, "Jesus, please have mercy on me." He said that he felt like the prophet Isaiah in the presence of the Lord.

> Woe is me, for I am undone! Because I am a man of unclean lips, And I
> dwell in the midst of a people of unclean lips; For my eyes have seen
> the King, The LORD of hosts. (Isa. 6:5)

He witnessed spectacular healings such as the deaf regaining their hearing and a woman getting out of her wheelchair, but what impressed him even more was when Kuhlman suddenly began to sob uncharacteristically.

> It continued for what seemed like two minutes. Then she thrust back
> her head.... It was a moment of incredible dimension. Still sobbing, she
> looked out at the audience and said with such agony, "Please." She
> seemed to stretch out the word, "Pleeease, don't grieve the Holy
> Spirit." She was begging. If you can imagine a mother pleading with a
> killer not to shoot her baby, it was like that. She begged and
> pleaded…. Then she continued her impassioned plea saying, "Please!
> Don't wound Him. He's all I've got. Don't wound the One I love!"....
> Kathryn Kuhlman was telling me about a person that was more real than
> you or I. pp. 18-19

Benny Hinn made it his quest to also know the person of whom Katherine spoke and recounted the story of how the Holy Spirit became his companion, counselor, teacher, and friend. He entitled his book after the greeting he called out every day upon awakening, ***“Good Morning, Holy Spirit”***.

Comment: Benny Hinn is a very controversial figure. I'm pretty sure this answer will trigger some downvotes because of it ...

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator  Well, sometimes the messenger gets shot. But Hinn is a trinitarian who strongly believes in the personhood of the Holy Spirit, and hopefully this will provoke thought about what a Christian's relationship with the Spirit whom Jesus sent as his replacement should look like.

Comment: I guess I should also add here that years ago I attended a Benny Hinn crusade not too far from my city and my scientific brain was not impressed. I believe in supernatural power and it seems foolish to me to put limitations on an all-powerful God, but I felt there was too much hype and not enough miraculous power for whatever reason. It didn't make me doubt the personhood or power of the Holy Spirit. I do think we should be careful about putting too much focus on the miraculous and put more on spiritual growth and holiness. Perhaps more real power for evangelism would result from that.