# Is there a specific term to denote an encounter with the Holy Spirit?

Tags: trinity, terminology, pneumatology, persons-of-the-trinity

Encounters with God (the Father) are called *Theophanies*, encounters with Jesus are called *Christophanies*, but what about encounters with the Holy Spirit? Is there a specific term for an encounter with the third person of the Trinity?

**Note**: by encounter, I mean any sort of self-authenticating experience through which a supernatural being makes its existence or presence known, obvious and clear (i.e. reveals itself) to a person.

---

Related: [According to Trinitarians, can the personhood of the Holy Spirit be verified experientially instead of just assented to intellectually?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/86291/50422)

Comment: According to [traditional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialogue_with_Trypho) Christianity, all theophanies are Christophanies; at any rate, the term you're looking for is [pneumatophany](http://www.google.com/search?q=pneumatophany), as in [pneumatology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumatology) or [pneumatomachi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumatomachi).

Comment: What do you mean an 'encounter' ? Are not  Christians full of the Holy Spirit at all times ?

Comment: @NigelJ - Is there a biblical basis for that statement?

Comment: @NigelJ - Regarding the word 'encounter', see the last edit.